# How to show whether the following sets are compact or not:

Tags: general-topology, compactness

How to show whether the following sets are compact or not:

$1.\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb R^3:x^2+2y^2-3z^2=1\}$

$2.\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb R^3:|x|+2|y|+3|z|\leq 1\}$

I know in order for a set to be compact it must be closed and bounded.But it is possible to check this $\Bbb R^2$ ,I can't do it for the above two sets

Comment: I would say neither is bounded, since in both cases no matter how large $x,y$ are you can always chooze a $z$ satisfying the equation. For example, let us choose $x_n=y_n=n$. Then $z_n=n$ makes $(x_n,y_n,z_n)\in\text{two}$. So 2 is clearly unbounded. For any $n$, you can find $z_n$ satisfying $3n^2-3z_n^2=1$: $z_n=\sqrt{n^2-\frac13}$. So $(x_n,y_n,z_n)\in\text{one}$ for all $n$, hence one is unbounded too.

Comment: Hm, 2 doesn't look compact either... Could you double check that it's copied correctly?

Comment: @Amartya, my mistake. I was thinking of something else.

Comment: With the + in 2, 2 becomes bounded, and being closed it is compact (cfr egreg's answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that both sets are closed, being inverse images of closed sets in $\mathbb{R}$ under continuous functions; the first set is the inverse image of $\{1\}$ under $(x,y,z)\mapsto x^2+2y^2-3z^2$; the second set is the inverse image of $(-\infty,1]$ under $(x,y,z)\mapsto|x|+2|y|-3|z|$.

The second set is
$$
\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3:|x|+2|y|+3|z|\le1\}
$$
and it is compact, because it's contained in the set $[-1,1]^3$; indeed, when $|x|>1$, $|y|>1$ and $|z|>1$, then $|x|+2|y|+3|z|>6$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If we want to show it's not bounded (and hence not compact), it suffices to find elements of arbitrarily large norm.

For example, for the first one, we can take $x$ and $y$ both as large as we like, and then just make $z$ big enough so the equation is satisfied. This would give us a norm as large as we want.

In this question, we can interpret this graphically (in 3D): the (usual) norm is the distance away from the origin, so we're looking for points that get arbitrarily far.